# Almacenar datos de una consulta guardada en un array, recorriendo con un for

Tags: php, array, mysqli

espero pueda obtener ayuda con mi duda, el punto es que tengo una tabla con campos id,nombre,codigo pais, telefono, grupo. Hago un select * de la tabla cuando el grupo sea tal seleccionado antes .. trato de hacer un for que me guarde cierto dato de ese array, pero lo estoy haciendo mal .. aqui el fragmento del codigo

```php
$sql =mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM directorio WHERE grupo = '$idPersona' ");
$datos= $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
for($i=0;$i<=count($datos);$i++){
    $receptor =$datos['codigo_pais'][$i].$datos['telefono_personal'][$i];
    $nombre= $datos['persona_nombre'][$i];
```

Aparte el count solo me bota el ultimo id mas no lo cuenta ejm mi ultimo id es 10 pero en la tabla solo tengo 3 registrados, ya que se debe a que hice unos delete de la tabla.

Comment: ¿Por que no utilizas un  foreach? Creo que es mas practico para esto

Answer (score 0):

Con mysqli_fetch_array sólo obtienes un registro, un array donde cada índice es el nombre del campo y el valor el valor del campo. 
No entiendo bien que quieres hacer. Cuantos registros esperas que traiga tu consulta?
Si esperas más de un registro debes hacer:

```
while ($datos= $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $receptor =$datos['codigo_pais'].$datos['telefono_personal'];
    $nombre= $datos['persona_nombre'];
//hacer algo con $receptor y $nombre porque en la siguiente iteración serán sobreescritos
}
```

Comment: Con `mysqli_fetch_array` no es que obtengas un solo registro, es que obtienes el resultado con un formato de array asociativo

Comment: Es lo que yo dije. Entiendo que lo que Alexander quiere hacer es bajar todo el resultset en un solo array, y no es así. Del manual de PHP:
"mysqli_fetch_array: Obtiene UNA FILA de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos". Para obtener todos los registros se debe usar fetch_all